# Is there a Rubocop configuration specifically for rails 5.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have just created a fresh Rails application using **Ruby 2.6.3** and **Rails 5.2.3** and the only thing I have done is installed **Rubocop**.

After installing **Rubocop v0.70.0**, and running `bundle exec rubocop` I get 89 offences. After running `rubocop -a` to fix them automatically, I am still left with 34 offences. Is there a configuration I am missing for a rails project or will I need to manually fix these offences?

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://github.com/toshimaru/rubocop-rails_config)? Or perhaps a (cut-down) version of [this](https://gist.github.com/dsandstrom/d9da0be5003c2217969a)?

Comment: The only main issues I find, really, is that you need to ignore stuff like the `db/`, `log/`, `node_modules/` and `bin/` folders - since they contain lots of auto-generated stuff which is likely not "rubocop-compliant" (depending on how you've configured it).

Comment: Thanks for your help, the rubocop-rails_config gem worked perfectly, 53 offences all autocorrected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses a code style that differs from rubocop default, but rubocop can be configured to enforce that.

For example see [.rubocop.yml from rails itself](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/.rubocop.yml), you can use that as a base for you own config, or use [rubocop-rails_config gem](https://github.com/toshimaru/rubocop-rails_config) (at time of writing it is not compatible with latest rubocop, but works fine with `gem "rubocop", "0.67.2"`, just tested - with this config only a few autocorrectable issues are present in newly created rails app)

Comment: Thanks, I downgraded to rubocop to 0.67.2 and installed the rubocop-rails_config, then after running 'rails generate rubocop_rails_config:install' it only found 53 issues which all autocorrected.